# I am unable to use clarity as as dependency

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I am starting a toy project in clojure. I decided to give it a try. I installed leiningen and clojure and I managed  run lein install and to work with it through emacs. Though, I am unable to use clarity as dependency of my project:

```
;;;project.clj
(defproject sms-client "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "This is meant to be an sms client"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
             [clarity "0.5.5"]])

;;;src/sms_client/core.clj
(ns sms-client.core
   (:require [clarity.form :as form]
             [clarity.dev :as dev]))

(def the-form
(form/form
  :login ""
  :password ""))

(dev/show-comp the-form)
```

This is blowing up with:

```
clojure.lang.RT.keyword(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lclojure/lang/Keyword;
  [Thrown class java.lang.NoSuchMethodError]

Restarts:
 0: [QUIT] Quit to the SLIME top level

Backtrace:
  0: clarity.component__init.__init0(Unknown Source)
  1: clarity.component__init.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
  2: java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  3: java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
  4: clojure.lang.RT.loadClassForName(RT.java:1578)
  5: clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:399)
  6: clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
  7: clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
  8: clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
  9: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
 10: clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
 11: clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
 12: clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
 13: clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
 14: clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
 15: clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
 16: clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
 17: clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:4881)
 18: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:619)
 19: clarity.form$eval1651$loading__4414__auto____1652.invoke(form.clj:1)
 20: clarity.form$eval1651.invoke(form.clj:1)
 21: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
 22: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
 23: clojure.lang.Compiler.load(Compiler.java:5857)
 24: clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:340)
 25: clojure.lang.RT.loadResourceScript(RT.java:331)
 26: clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:409)
 27: clojure.lang.RT.load(RT.java:381)
 28: clojure.core$load$fn__4519.invoke(core.clj:4915)
 29: clojure.core$load.doInvoke(core.clj:4914)
 30: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:408)
 31: clojure.core$load_one.invoke(core.clj:4729)
 32: clojure.core$load_lib.doInvoke(core.clj:4766)
 33: clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:142)
 34: clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
 35: clojure.core$load_libs.doInvoke(core.clj:4800)
 36: clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
 37: clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:542)
 38: clojure.core$require.doInvoke(core.clj:4881)
 39: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:421)
 40: sms_client.core$eval1645$loading__4414__auto____1646.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
 41: sms_client.core$eval1645.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
 42: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
 43: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5415)
 44: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
 45: clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
 46: swank.commands.basic$eval_region.invoke(basic.clj:47)
 47: swank.commands.basic$eval_region.invoke(basic.clj:37)
 48: swank.commands.basic$eval849$listener_eval__850.invoke(basic.clj:71)
 49: clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:365)
 50: user$eval1641.invoke(NO_SOURCE_FILE)
 51: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5424)
 52: clojure.lang.Compiler.eval(Compiler.java:5391)
 53: clojure.core$eval.invoke(core.clj:2382)
 54: swank.core$eval_in_emacs_package.invoke(core.clj:92)
 55: swank.core$eval_for_emacs.invoke(core.clj:239)
 56: clojure.lang.Var.invoke(Var.java:373)
 57: clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:167)
 58: clojure.lang.Var.applyTo(Var.java:482)
 59: clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
 60: swank.core$eval_from_control.invoke(core.clj:99)
 61: swank.core$eval_loop.invoke(core.clj:104)
 62: swank.core$spawn_repl_thread$fn__617$fn__618.invoke(core.clj:309)
 63: clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
 64: clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
 65: clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
 66: swank.core$spawn_repl_thread$fn__617.doInvoke(core.clj:306)
 67: clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
 68: clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
 69: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with clarity "0.5.5" its the `require` that is blowing up:

```
user=> (require 'clarity.form)         
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: clojure.lang.RT.keyword(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Lclojure/lang/Keyword; (form.clj:1)
```

clarity "0.5.5" seems not to work with clojure 1.2.1 but does work with clojure 1.3.0
you can
work with clarity "0.5.3" and stick with clojure 1.2.1 or stay with clarity 0.5.5 and switch to clojure 1.3.0.

Personally i recommend using the latest versions of both.

Answer (score 4):

This was AOT compilation making the library jar incompatible with Clojure 1.2. I didn't mean to drop support for 1.2, so I have fixed this and just released Clarity 0.5.6. Thanks for the feedback!